# How to subdivide a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been looking around google for solutions to this problem, however it is quite specific, so I am having trouble finding a proper strategy to solve this.
Let's say i have a dataframe like this:

```
name    trajectory_id    lat    long
0       1                 -       -
0       1                 -       -
.       .                 .       .
.       .                 .       .
.       .                 .       .
0       40                -       -
0       40                -       -
```

Essentially i have a number of trajectories that can have different length. 
I want to subdivide this dataframe by dividing each trajectory in to
segments of equal length. If the trajectory cannot be divided fully, then the last segment can be shorter. I have considered doing this using a loop, over
a dataframe that is grouped by "trajectory_id", adding another column indicating
segement number e.g.:

```
name    trajectory_id    lat    long    segment_id
0       1                 -       -         0
0       1                 -       -         0
.       .                 .       .
.       .                 .       .
.       .                 .       .
0       40                -       -        150
0       40                -       -        150
```

I feel that this is a wrong approach to the problem, and I am looking for
a more pandaish solution. Thank you !

Comment: So you want to divide each trajectory in segments? From your example it seems that `trajectory 1` has two same segments. Could you clarify please?

Comment: The second example has the same number of rows as the first dataframe. However the segment_id simply states which segment the row belongs to. That was my first approach as i want to be able to groupby based on the segment_id. (Notice that each trajectory in the first dataframe, can have a number of rows associated with it, typically more than 100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates trajectories of random length and appends a segment id, I hope I understood you correctly.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

seg_length = 3

# Generate data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=(50,))), columns=['trajectory_id'])

# Create id for each segment grouped on trajectory_id
df['rk'] = np.ceil((df.groupby(['trajectory_id']).cumcount()+1)/seg_length)

# Final segment_id
f,i = pd.factorize(df[['trajectory_id','rk']].apply(tuple,1))
df['segment_id'] = f
```